# Pointer changes size on function call (checked using gdb)

Tags: c, pointers, gdb

I have a program that passes a character pointer and the function that it is passed on to populates it with strings. However, I noticed that the data were truncated. Upon investigation using gdb, it seems that there is a difference in the size of the pointers.

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned char *test_char;

    test_char = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 6);
    memset(test_char, 0x00, sizeof(unsigned char) * 6);

    functionToPopulate(test_char);
}

void functionToPopulate(unsigned char *test_char) {
    snprintf(test_char, sizeof(test_char), "%u%s%u", 20, ":", 30);
}
```

In this situation, I used gdb before memset, and printed the value of test_char. It says (6). During and after snprintf, I used gdb again to print the value of test_char. It says (4). However, upon return, the value says (6) again. However, the data has already been truncated. Instead of "20:30", it becomes "20:".

Comment: The size of a pointer is not the same as the size of what it's pointing to.  The size of a pointer cannot change.

Answer (score 1):

Before the call to `functiontopopulate` you call `malloc sizeof(unsigned char) * 6` which returns 6 sizeof(unsigned char) is 1 * 6= 6. Inside the function you call sizeof(test_char) which is the size of a (unsigned char *) the size of the pointer is 4.  When you need to pass an array in c you must always pass the size of the array as c does not maintain it.

Comment: In addition, please note that `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1, so you can remove the two instances of it and make the code clearer. Also, you should *never* cast return value of `malloc` in C.